# Recreating Facebook Comment Button. Submiting an ajax form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook

I'm trying to recreate the Facebook comment button. Right now, Facebook comments can only be submitted by pressing enter. I've successfully added a comment button to every textarea, but now I'm having trouble submitting the form. This is my code:

```
$('.UFILikeLink').after(' · <span><a class="submitbtn">Submit</a></span>');

$('.submitbtn').live('click', function(){       
    $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
});
```

The form submits to a page which is meant to be called with AJAX, giving me an error.

Comment: Showing us your HTML would help. Also, it doesn't sound like you're actually using AJAX at all - are you using jquery.form.js or something like that? Is the AJAX itself the part you need help with?

Comment: The HTML can be found by going on Facebook.com. This is a chrome extension that is adding a comment button to allow users to submit a comment by clicking instead of pressing enter.